Prove that this limit is equal to $\sqrt{2}$ for the function $f(x)=x^2-2$ for an arbitrary seed point $s$.
Mathematica knows that:
$$
s  +  \frac{1}{1-\lim_\limits{n\ \to\ \infty}\left[\frac{\displaystyle\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1}}{f\left(k/n + s -1/n\right)}}{\displaystyle\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1}}{f\left(k/n + s\right)}}\right]} =
\sqrt{2}
$$
where:
$$f(x)=x^2-2$$
and where the seed point is $s=3$, or some other value.

Can you prove it so that I can understand it?

The formula follows from the ratios of consecutive higher order derivatives plus the seed point, but I am not interested in that explanation, because that was my starting point. I want to know the computational approach in finding the limit given above.
Mathematica 14:
(*start*)
Clear[n, k, s, f, g];
f[x_] = x^2 - 2
s = 3; (* = the seed point*)
s + 1/(1 - 
    Limit[Sum[(-1)^(k - 1)*
        Binomial[n - 1, k - 1]/f[s + k/n - 1/n], {k, 1, n}]/
      Sum[(-1)^(k - 1)*Binomial[n - 1, k - 1]/f[s + k/n], {k, 1, n}], 
     n -> Infinity])
FullSimplify[%]
(*end*)

which gives the output:
$$3+\frac{1}{\frac{e^{\frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3-\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4-\sqrt{2}}-\frac{6}{3-\sqrt{2}}+\frac{4}{4-\sqrt{2}}+1} \sqrt{\frac{14 \left(5-3 \sqrt{2}\right)}{3-\sqrt{2}}}}{\sqrt{2}-3}+1}$$
which in turn Mathematica 14 simplifies to:
$$\sqrt{2}$$

So to be clear, you know this is right (because of how you derived it) for all $s$? And we're trying to show that the limit is equal to $1-\frac{1}{\sqrt2-s}$, is that correct?

Yes. I should perhaps add the output from Mathematica. This is my first post about it: https://mathoverflow.net/q/375886/25104

That Mathematica output is pretty strange! For what it's worth, the power to which $e$ is raised in that expression, $\frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3-\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4-\sqrt{2}}-\frac{6}{3-\sqrt{2}}+\frac{4}{4-\sqrt{2}}+1$ is actually $0$.

Also, Mathematica is not able to give the exact answer in radicals, for other functions than the quadratic equation. Already for the cubic equation Mathematica computes forever without output.
